# year month day select boxes change each other javascript

Tags: javascript

I have three select boxes one for each of the year month and day and I need the month to change the day select box to the appropriate days and the year select box to make the month checkbox make the day checkbox correct for leap year.

My 'shortened' HTML is

```
<select name="year">
<option>2000</option>
<option>2001</option>
<option>2002</option>
<option>2003</option>
<option>2004</option>
</select>

<selec name="month">
<option>Jan</option>
<option>Feb</option>
<option>Mar</option>
<option>Apr</option>
<option>May</option>
<option>Jun</option>
<option>Jul</option>
<option>Aug</option>
<option>Sep</option>
<option>Oct</option>
<option>Nov</option>
<option>Dec</option>
</select>

<select name="day">
<option>1</option>
...etc...
</select>
```

Comment: and what did you try doing?

Comment: You would be better off using any one of the huge number of existing date select controls rather than trying to create your own.

Comment: any suggestions on a good date select control?